# Selenium webdriver python not typing on password field

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, input, webdriver

I made this code and it works, the only problem is when typing on password field. Doesnt appear anything. Can you help me please?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import threading

userStr = '555555'
passwordStr = '555555'

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(('https://www30.mercantilbanco.com/olb/Login'))

username = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#userId')
username.send_keys(userStr)

password = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#password')
username.send_keys(passwordStr)
```

Comment: Can you add the error to your question?

Comment: @live2 done sir, i edited the post

Comment: I think the reason is your url don't contains the input field it is a frame try on this url `https://www30.mercantilbanco.com/olb/Login`

Comment: @live2 thank you so much! it worked

Comment: @live2 you are very helpful, i got another error can you help me with it? it doesnt type on password